# Photo selector API for Ubuntu Touch

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I searched all over the web, but I can't find anything that could help me. I am looking for an API to implement a photo selector in my Ubuntu Touch application. I need something like a File Chooser dialog which would allow me to select photo files from across the filesystem.

Does something like this exist??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen a way to do it in https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-read. You should have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You're able to view folders and files in a list view I believe. I've never actually implemented this myself but it can be done with a listview so it won't look anything like a `QFileDialog` from Qt. Check out the following resources, hopefully they help.

[Resource 1](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/src-imports-folderlistmodel.html)

[Resource 2](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-folderlistmodel.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Ubuntu ContentHub

https://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-1.0/Ubuntu.Content.ContentHub/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, Could you please explain in more depth what ContentHub is and how it works?